# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class [Ch. 9 MHartl Tutorial]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Wrapping up the Mhartl rails tutorial and I've been hit with this error.

**Error message:**

```
NoMethodError in Users#edit

Showing /Users/ME/Sites/rails_projects_updated/first_app/app/views/users/edit.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: 
4: <div class="row">
5:   <div class="span6 offset3">
6:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
7:       <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
8: 
9:       <%= f.label :name %>
```

**Edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @user = User.new

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

   def create
       @user = User.new(params[:user])
       if @user.save
         sign_in @user
         flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
         redirect_to @user
       else
         render 'new'
       endx
     end

       def edit
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
       end

       def update
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
         if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
           # Handle a successful update.
         else
           render 'edit'
         end
       end
     end
   end
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other controllers/views/models and I will update the post with them accordingly!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create controller has an endx where it should have an end.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    ...
  endx
end
```

Should be

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
   ...
  end
end
```